Simple add and sub in asm and printing to output window
Why only result of addition is printed but not subtruct as well
section .data
    num1    dq 5              ; First number (64-bit integer)
    num2    dq 2              ; Second number (64-bit integer)
    mathResult db 'Mat result is %d', 0ah, 0

section .text
    global main               ; Define the main function (entry point)
    extern printf             ; Link to printf from MSVCRT
    extern ExitProcess        ; Link to ExitProcess from Kernel32

main:
    sub rsp, 40               ; Align the stack (Windows ABI requires 16-byte alignment)

    ; Addition
    mov rax, [num1]
    add rax, [num2]
    call display_result

    ; Subtraction
    mov rax, [num1]
    sub rax, [num2]
    call display_result

display_result:
    mov rcx, mathResult       ; Use the same message for both operations
    mov rdx, rax
    call printf
    ret

exit_program:
    xor ecx, ecx              ; Set exit code to 0 (ECX = 0)
    call ExitProcess          ; Call ExitProcess to terminate the program


You misalign the stack and do not allocate shadow space in display_result. Put sub rsp, 40 and add rsp, 40 in there.  Also your exit_program block is in the wrong place should be before the display_result.

@Jester thanks. That solved the problem. But why exit_program block is in the wrong place? Is there a rule which block goes where?

The exit_program is not reached because after the call display_result returns it will again fall through into display_result and hit the ret which will then crash.
